# addEventListener to ALL INPUT elements when DOM changes

Tags: javascript, dom

At the moment I'm doing the following when the document is complete.

```
var passwordInputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=password]");

for (index = 0; index < passwordInputs.length; ++index) {
    passwordInputs[index].addEventListener("focusin", activeWordsFocusIn);
    passwordInputs[index].addEventListener("focusout", activeWordsFocusOut);
}
```

Which works as expected. However if the page has some additional script which modifies the DOM and adds more `input` elements then they are not hooked.

How can add event handlers for ALL `input` elements, even those added to the DOM thru script/ajax?

**Not a duplicate** I don't consider this a duplicate as this question [Detect Changes in the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom) which focuses on detecting changes in the DOM. My questions focus is on adding an `eventListener` to all `input` elements even when the DOM changes. I have since added my own answer to this now.

Comment: This is related more to event delegation with JS then detecting DOM changes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use event delegation to add an event handler to the container of the inputs. When an element inside the container triggers an event, 
we check if the element [matches](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) the selector, and if so, the event handler is called.

```js
const delegate = (selector) => (cb) => (e) => e.target.matches(selector) && cb(e);

const inputDelegate = delegate('input[type=password]');

container.addEventListener('focusin', inputDelegate((el) => console.log('focus in', el.target.name)));

container.addEventListener('focusout', inputDelegate((el) => console.log('focus out', el.target.name)));

setTimeout(() => {
  const input = document.createElement('input');
  input.setAttribute('type', 'password');
  input.setAttribute('name', 'input2');
  
  container.append(input);
}, 2000);
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <input type="password" name="input1">
</div>
```

Comment: clean solution thanks - does chrome support `matches`?

Comment: Yep. It's actually has a very good support. It's even supported by IE9 (with a prefix).

Comment: I've not seen code snippets in stackoverflow before ... what is the `container` object?

Comment: There isn't a container object. It's a reference to the div with the id of `container`. When you use an `id` in html, a global variable to element with the id is created. To make a long story short - it's like an automatic `getElementById()`, and a very good reason not to use ids.

Comment: got it ... wondering of any advantages over the answer I suggested. Yours looks cleaner, anything else?

Comment: I was aiming for generic and reusable using partial application. The selector is external, so you use it for different elements. Because of the partial application, after entering a selector, you can a function you can use for multiple by supplying a callback for each.

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution I have found that works...

```
function activeWordsFocusIn(e) {
    if (isPassword(e)) {
        console.log("focus in");
    }
}

function activeWordsFocusOut(e) {
    if (isPassword(e)) {
        console.log("focus out");
    }
}

function isPassword(e) {
    var e = window.e || e;

    if (e.target.tagName !== 'INPUT')
        return false;

    if (e.target.type !== 'password')
        return false;

    return true;
}

document.addEventListener('focusin', activeWordsFocusIn, false);
document.addEventListener('focusout', activeWordsFocusOut, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
inputs.forEach((input) => {
    input.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
        console.log("Clicked:", event.target.name);
        console.log("Value of Clicked Input:", event.target.value);
    });
});
```